# How to have same http interceptor across multiple angular projects?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, micro-frontend

I have 5 different projects having same http interceptor code.
Each time there is a change in the interceptor code, that has to be done at 5 different places.

Is there any way, by which this code can be made as generic code.

Comment: Make a library?

Comment: Actually, i am new for library part, can you provide some links or stackblitz code ? @DaveNewton